# Can an attacker recover the key if a Poly1305 collision is known?

Tags: mac, poly1305, universal-hash

Suppose that messages $m_1$ and $m_2 \neq m_1$, both known to the attacker, are both MAC'd through Poly1305 with the same key.  By chance, these two messages hash to the same value.  The attacker knows that $\operatorname{Poly1305}(m_1) = \operatorname{Poly1305}(m_2)$ but not the values of the auth tags (e.g. if they were passed through Blake2 with a secret key).

What attacks can the attacker mount? Can the attacker recover the secret key?

What if Poly1305 is replaced by GHASH or VHASH?

Comment: Rather than MACing the MAC, why not just use the outer MAC for the whole message?

Comment: @pg1989 Speed.  Some inner MACs are FAR faster than Blake2.

Comment: Why don't you use Poly1305 as it was designed -- with a one-time key?

Comment: I am wondering about slow embedded implementations with low entropy availability.  I didn't know how fast Keccak and Blake2 are (very fast) at the time I asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, the attacker can recover the key with high probability in the event of such a collision.**  For example, in two-block messages $m_1 \mathbin\| m_2$ and $m'_1 \mathbin\| m'_2$, this means that $$m_1 r^2 + m_2 r = m'_1 r^2 + m'_2 r,$$ so the key $r$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial $$(m_1 - m'_1) r^2 + (m_2 - m'_2) r,$$ of which there are at most two possibilities, one of which is necessarily zero and the other of which you can probably find in your head by this point.<sup>*</sup>  The same goes for longer messages with more work and more roots to sift through.  Exactly the same analysis applies to GHASH, which like Poly1305 is a polynomial evaluation hash; similar analysis will tend to apply to other universal hash families.

**But the nice thing about Poly1305—or any suitable choice of universal hash family—is that the probability of this event is negligible, well below $2^{-100}$, which is good news for the composition as a candidate PRF, and thus also as a candidate MAC.**

In particular, suppose the PRF-distinguishing advantage of any adversary against $F$ is bounded by $\varepsilon_F$, and suppose the hash family $H$ (*e.g.*, Poly1305, GHASH, *etc.*) has collision probability bounded by $\varepsilon_H$.  Then PRF-distinguishing advantage of any adversary making $q$ oracle queries against $m \mapsto F_k(H_r(m))$ is bounded by $\varepsilon_F + \binom{q}{2}\varepsilon_H$ ([proof](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59218)).

Thus this technique is a good way to build a long-input, short-output PRF out of a short-input, short-output PRF and a universal hash family.  This structure is used by, for example, AES-GCM-SIV.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Strictly speaking, there may be more possible values of $r$ because the polynomial evaluation giving an integer representative in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2^{130} - 2\}$ is further reduced mod $2^{128}$ to make the Poly1305 authenticator.  But this only multiplies the possibilities by a small number, at most 4.</sub>