# Is XSalsa20-Poly1305-SIV a reasonable choice for nonce-misuse-resistant authenticated encryption?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, salsa20, poly1305, chacha, xsalsa20

Consider XSalsa20-Poly1305-SIV.  This is obtained by:

- computing a MAC $t_{secret}$ of the plaintext from the key and nonce, as in ChaCha20-Poly1305 except that the plaintext, not the ciphertext, is MAC'd.
- compute $t = F(K,t_{secret})$, where F is the ChaCha20 core (or any other PRF).
- use $t$ as the auth tag and as part of the XSalsa20 nonce.

Questions:

- Is this secure?
- Is this provably secure, assuming that the ChaCha20 and Salsa20 cores are strong PRFs?

Comment: If you're writing F's inputs in the usual order then that's certainly not necessarily secure. ​ ​

Comment: @RickiDemer oops, fixes.

Comment: Assuming I've understood what you're asking, your question is equivalent to: "Is SIV a secure mode of operation", which it is [http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/keywrap.html]

Answer (score 3):

This can be a secure construction, if by MAC you mean universal hash family, like Poly1305.  Call this hash family $H_r$ and the *short* pseudorandom function family $F_k$.  Rough justification for why this is secure:

1. The function $m \mapsto F_k(H_r(m))$ is a *long*-input, short-output PRF.
2. A good PRF makes a good MAC.
3. A good PRF has birthday-bounded collision probability, so the probability of nonce reuse for the stream cipher is small.

In a bit more detail: Let $\varepsilon_F$ be a bound on the PRF-distinguisher advantage of any algorithm making $q$ queries against $F$, and let $\varepsilon_H$ be a bound on the collision probability $\Pr[H_r(x) = H_r(y)]$ of $H$ for any $x \ne y$ and uniform random $r$.

- The PRF-distinguisher advantage for a $q$-query attack against $m \mapsto F_k(H_r(m))$ is bounded by $\varepsilon_F + \binom{q}{2} \varepsilon_H$ ([proof](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59218)).
- For fixed-size keys, the collision probability $\varepsilon_H$ grows linearly with the maximum message length.  So this figures into the concrete numbers.
- The probability of a synthetic nonce collision (*i.e.*, a collision in $m \mapsto F_k(H_r(m))$) is higher than the probability of a collision in $H$, because *either* a collision in $H$ *or* a collision in $F$ means there's a nonce collision—whether this matters depends on how large the output of $F$ is, and in particular on the birthday bound for $F$ which may be much smaller than the collision probability of $H$.

There's some practical details to work out.

Here $q$ represents the number of messages that you are willing to send or receive in your application.  For example, if $\varepsilon \approx 2^{-100}$, the bound above means nothing unless your application's total bandwidth is limited to $q \lll 2^{50}$ messages.  (And you don't want to [mess with collisions in $H$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67854).)

Is the Poly1305 collision probability bound $\varepsilon_{\operatorname{Poly1305}} = 8\ell/2^{106}$ for $16\ell$-byte messages comfortable enough for trillions of megabyte-long messages?  Maybe it is, maybe it isn't—for now I leave it as an exercise for the reader to compute specific bounds for specific data volumes.  (See a [similar table for AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67367).)

What should you choose for $F_k$?  If you're already using XSalsa20, the obvious choice is XSalsa20 truncated to 128 bits or similar.  Of course, you'll have to quantify the probability of a collision between the XSalsa20 nonce used for encryption and the XSalsa20 input from $H$.  But maybe you can do better than multiple the HSalsa20 invocations this would imply, each of which adds overhead to small packets.  Maybe you should use a 192-bit or 256-bit hash $H$, and a 192-bit authentication tag, so that the probability of a synthetic nonce collision is negligible even for extremely large volumes of data.